# Set Value in Select Option of dynamic form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, dynamic-forms

I have created dynamic form, in that form there is one dropdown. In that dropdown I want to have fiscal week for that I want to run loop inside ts function.

form.ts -

```
<div class="col-md-9" [ngSwitch]="field.type">
    <dropdown *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [field]="field" [form]="form"></dropdown>
</div>
```

dropdown.ts -

```
public field: any[] = [
    {
      type: 'dropdown',
      name: 'fiscalweek',
      label: 'fiscalweek',
      placeholder: 'Fiscal Week',
      required: true,
      options: this.getWeek()
    }
];

getWeek(){
    this.week = 

    [
      { key: 'Select', label: 'ALL'},
      { key: '1', label: '1'},
      { key: '2', label: '2'},
      { key: '3', label: '3'},
      { key: '4', label: '4'},
      { key: '5', label: '5'},
      { key: '6', label: '6'},
      .
      .
      .
      { key: '53', label: '53'}
    ]
    ;

    return this.week;
  }
```

I want to run a loop inside this getWeek from 1 to 53 instead of hardcoding.

Can someone please suggest me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate `week` array by a simple for loop

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7buya?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
 getWeek() {
    this.week = [];
    this.week.push({ key: "Select", label: "ALL" });
    for (var i = 1; i <= 53; i++) {
      this.week.push({ key: i.toString(), label: i.toString() });
    }
    return this.week;
 }
```